# Django: How to combine two attributes of a class into another attribute of the same class?

Tags: python, django

I want to combine two CharField attributes of a class into another attribute of the same class.

In pseudocode would be something like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    full_name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Then I want to be able to use full_name like this:

```
>>> Client.objects.create(first_name="John", last_name="Smith")
>>> c=Client.objects.get(name="John")
>>> c.last_name
u'Smith'
>>> c.full_name
u'John Smith'
```

How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Why not have a method of your objectthat just returns what you want? : ) If you duplicate the model field itself, you'll end up with an extra (unnecessary) column in your database.

Comment: what do you intend here: `get(name="John")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a method in model for that:

```
def full_name(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Then use:

```
c.full_name()
```

Or convert it to a property:

```
@property
def full_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Then you can simply do:

```
c.full_name
```

Comment: Plus, in a template you won't be able to tell the difference. ;)